# Toggle switch css issue

Tags: html, css, reactjs, label

I was using a toggle switch in my code it was working well.

I change some stuff in my project and now, two arrrows and a white vertical line appears on my switch and I don't understand why and where it comes from :(

There, a picture :

my toggle switch

[image: 1]

My code :

```
function Dashboard() {
    return (
      <>
         <label className="switch">
            <input type="checkbox"/>
            <span className="slider round"></span>
          </label>
      </>
    );
}
```

I used this page for css : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp

Comment: add your code as code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this pseudo class [Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hide_arrow_number.asp)!

```
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Firefox */
input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried and it didn't work, but i found a way :).

Like :

```
  .switch::before { display: none; }
  .switch::after { display: none; }
```

Thank you for your help